# INSERT into a table records extracted from another table by query with variable

Tags: javascript, web-sql

I'm trying to write a query that extracts and transforms data from a table and then inserts into another table. It is working if I add string but when I add variable it doesn't. It gave me empty table!

```
function dodb() {

    var name = document.getElementsByName('prezime');
    var elements = document.getElementsByName('bt');

    for (var i = 0; i <= elements.length; i++) {
        var oelements = elements[i];
        oelements.onclick = (function(){
        var name1 = name[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
        return function() {
            db.transaction(function (tx) {
                var a = "INSERT INTO racersA SELECT * FROM racers WHERE prezime=%name1%";
                tx.executeSql(a);
            });
        }
        })(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: i have never seen anything like this before would you tell more about it?

Comment: i have database with two tables, want transfer data from one database table to other table by click on button, get value from nodeValue and add that in query to transfer data to a second table

Comment: if i use: tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO racersA SELECT * FROM racers WHERE prezime='Aristida stricta'"); i get it in other table racersA, i want use variable instead of string   tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO racersA SELECT * FROM racers WHERE prezime='name1'");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't put any variables into your SQL, so since its simple Javascript you need to concatenate your variable with your string

Should be

```
var a = "INSERT INTO racersA SELECT * FROM racers WHERE prezime='" + name1 + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, use parameterize SQL

```
var a = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO racersA SELECT * FROM racers WHERE prezime = ?";
tx.executeSql(a, [name]);
```